# Input value attribute not showing full text on search bar

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

My code is a web application using Flask (python) framework, I have this search bar implemented on HTML5 and I want the text inputted for search to appear on the search bar after the page loads; like this (where {{query}} is a variable passed on by Jinja2):

```
    <form class="search-bar search_header" method="GET" action="/">
    <input class="search_input" name="q" tabindex="1" type="text" value={{query}}>
    <button class="search_button" tabindex="2" type="submit">
        <i class="icon-search"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

The problem is that only the text up until the first white space is displayed, the rest is cutoff, so "This is an example" will display "This" in the search bar. If I pass on a regular string instead of the variable then it works fine.

{{query}} is of type unicode, if that matters, and I have tried formatting it in several ways to no avail, is there any workaround to this?

I have also thought about saving the variable as Javascript from the landing page search bar html, but I am new at Javascript, any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I expect you have to wrap the placeholder in double quotes:

```
<input class="search_input" name="q" tabindex="1" type="text" value="{{query}}">
```

Otherwise the substituted html code would be

```
<input class="search_input" name="q" tabindex="1" type="text" value=text with whitespace>
```

The commonplace html renderer would parse this into an input element with attributes `value`, `with` and `whitespace`,  the latter two coming without a value while `value`'s value would be `text`. Note that most html renderers are tolerant against attributes which are undefined and value-less attributes are covered by the standard (as it is to omit the double quotes).

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly! why is it that you have to wrap it in double quotes?

Comment: See the added explanation.